# What this Statement will return

Tags: if-statement, return

```
return p? p->height : 0;
```

Can someone please explain me what this statement means, I know ? : means if and else but I'am confused with return statement.

What i Understand from this Statement is that it will return p if height exist or else it will return 0, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say "height exist", it's rather if `p` isn't null.

Comment: Is there any other way to write this statement?

Comment: Explain what you expect, this question is too much open.

Comment: Can we write it as `if(p != null) return p-> height else 0;`

Comment: Absolutely, I encourage you to avoid the "old fashioned" C style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question mark expression `p ? p->height : 0;` evaluates to one of `p->height` or `0`, depending on the value of `p`.

And this is precisely what the function returns.

Answer (score 2):

It essentially means:

```
if p evaluates to true:
    return p->height
else
    return 0
```

ternary conditional operator is just a short way to write this.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer IMHO as you have referenced that this is using the ternary operator. +1.